# get the filenames of the images inside folders using php

Tags: php

I have the below folder structure.

`main_folder
   subfolder1
      image001.jpg
      image002.jpg
      image003.jpg
   subfolder2
      image001.jpg
      image002.jpg
      image002.jpg
      image004.jpg
      image005.jpg
   subfolder3
      image001.jpg
      image002.jpg
      image002.jpg
      image004.jpg`

I want to get the `pathname` and `filename` of each image. I know I can use `pathinfo($File);` to get it, but I can't get into the folders and the sub-folders. I tried the following code to make this possible, but it is not working.

```
function listFolderFiles($dir)
{
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..')
        {
            echo '<li>'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}

listFolderFiles('/main_folder/');
```

Comment: Check out recursive directory iterator: http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Answer (score 2):

Try [glob](http://php.net/glob) to easy to get all filename inside the folder

Something like:

```
foreach(glob('./images/*.*') as $filename){
     echo $filename;
 }
```

Comment: This does not show the name of the images, rather the directories